# How to get and unite spesific amount using where clause and make this 3 times in one table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT OfferSK, DateSK, UsedAmount, PaidAmount, ChargedAmount
FROM
  (SELECT OfferSK, DateSK, Amount as UsedAmount
   FROM dwh.FactExtraExpenses
   where FinOperationSK = 2
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT OfferSK, DateSK, Amount as PaidAmount
   FROM dwh.FactExtraExpenses
   where FinOperationSK = 1
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT OfferSK, DateSK, Amount as ChargedAmount
   FROM dwh.FactExtraExpenses
   where FinOperationSK in (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10)) FCP
order by DateSK
```

Hello, in one column (`Amount`) in one table (`FactExtraExpenses`) I have amounts for different cases like used amount (`FinOperationSK = 2`) or paid amount(FinOperationSK = 1) or some fee/interst (`FinOperationSK in (3,4,5,6,7,10)`). Im trying to take all in one table, ordered by day by day (`DateSK`) for every customer (`OfferSK`). So i do something but is not ok :) Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select OfferSK, DateSK,
       sum(case when FinOperationSK = 2 then Amount else 0 end) as UsedAmount,
       sum(case when FinOperationSK = 1 then Amount else 0 end) as PaidAmount,
       sum(case when in (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10) then Amount else 0 end) as ChargedAmount
from dwh.FactExtraExpenses
group by OfferSK, DateSK;
```

Comment: Amazing! Very fast and accurate answer! Thanks Gordon!